# Generic approach to dealing with multiple result sets from EF stored procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

- EF 6, .NET 4.51

I am trying to build a generic helper class that will help me "translate" each of the result sets into a type safe class as described here [Handle multiple result from a stored procedure with SqlQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25304791/handle-multiple-result-from-a-stored-procedure-with-sqlquery/25305607#25305607)

For my solution I want to pass the following to my helper class (MultiResultsetsHelper):

1. Generic Return Type
2. ObjectContext
3. DataReader
4. List of class types **in order** of the result sets coming back

and then have the helper class do the heavy lifting of populating 1. Below is the code so far:

**Classes For Result**

```
public class Set1ReturnDto
{
    public int CruiseCount { get; set; }
    public string DisplayText { get; set; }
    public int DisplayValue { get; set; }
}

public class Set2ReturnDto
{
    public string DepartingFrom { get; set; }
    public string Port_Code { get; set; }
}

public class DummyReturnDto
{
    public DummyReturnDto()
    {
        Set1 = new List<Set1ReturnDto>();
        Set2 = new List<Set2ReturnDto>();
    }

    public List<Set1ReturnDto> Set1 { get; set; }
    public List<Set2ReturnDto> Set2 { get; set; }
}
```

**Low Level Database Call**

```
    public static DummyReturnDto DonoUspGetSideBarList(DbContext aDbContext, out int aProcResult)
    {
        SqlParameter procResultParam = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@procResult", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };

        DbCommand dbCommand = aDbContext.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(procResultParam);
        dbCommand.CommandText = "EXEC @procResult = [dbo].[usp_GetSideBarList] ";
        dbCommand.Transaction = aDbContext.Database.CurrentTransaction.UnderlyingTransaction;

        DbDataReader reader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();
        aProcResult = -1;

        // Drop down to the wrapped `ObjectContext` to get access to the `Translate` method
        ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)aDbContext).ObjectContext;

        List<Type> containedDtos = new List<Type>
                                   {
                                       typeof (List<Set1ReturnDto>), 
                                       typeof (List<Set1ReturnDto>)
                                   };

        return MultiResultsetsHelper.Process<DummyReturnDto>(reader, objectContext, containedDtos);
    }
```

The resulting datasets returned are:

[image]

**Helper Class**

```
public static class MultiResultsetsHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Given a data reader that contains multiple result sets, use the supplied object context to serialise the
    ///     rows of data in the result set into our property.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of the containing object that contains all the various result sets.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="aDbReader">Database reader that contains all the result sets returned from the database.</param>
    /// <param name="aObjectContext">Data context associated with the data reader.</param>
    /// <param name="aContainedDataSetReturnedTypes">
    ///     List of types in order of which the result sets are contained within the
    ///     data reader. We will serilize sequentially each result set the data reader contains
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>Retuns an object representing all the result sets returned by the data reader.</returns>
    public static T Process<T>(DbDataReader aDbReader, ObjectContext aObjectContext, List<Type> aContainedDataSetReturnedTypes) where T : new()
    {
        //What we will be returning
        T result = new T();

        for (int datasetNdx = 0; datasetNdx < aContainedDataSetReturnedTypes.Count; datasetNdx++)
        {
            //Advance the reader if we are not looking at the first dataset
            if (datasetNdx != 0)
                aDbReader.NextResult();

            //Get the property we are going to be updating based on the type of the class we will be filling
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof (T).GetProperties().Single(p => p.PropertyType == aContainedDataSetReturnedTypes[datasetNdx]);

            //Now get the object context to deserialize what is in the resultset into our type
            var valueForProperty = aObjectContext.Translate <aContainedDataSetReturnedTypes[datasetNdx]> (aDbReader);

            //Finally we update the property with the type safe information
            propertyInfo.SetValue(result, valueForProperty, null);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

However currently I cannot get this to compile.

> Error 2   Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method
>   group' and 'System.Type'

Can someone help out? Ultimately it has to do with how we use reflection and the passed in aContainedDataSetReturnedTypes. I am happy to change things around as long as it is still easy to call MultiResultsetsHelper.Process<>()

Comment: what entity type does `EXEC @procResult = [dbo].[usp_GetSideBarList]` returns?

Comment: It returns two datasets. The first one has fields as per Set1ReturnDto and the second one has fields as per Set2ReturnDto

Comment: I would combine the two `POCO` classes together to create another class that represents the result set, then use `context.Database.SqlQuery<JoinedPocoClass>("stored proc")` then use `Select` on that to project out into the separate `POCO` classes

Comment: Unless, you can fire off the `sproc` twice to give the two different results sets, then I would just fire `SqlQuery` strongly typed with the two `POCO` classes

Comment: @CallumLinington Isnt JoinedPocoClass actually my class DummyReturnDto?

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
aObjectContext.Translate<aContainedDataSetReturnedTypes[datasetNdx]>
```

will not work, because generic type parameters are always resolved at compile-time. You can't pass a `Type` instance at runtime.

You can still call the generic method, but you'll have to [use reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method).

Comment: OK so using reflection as MethodInfo method = typeof(ObjectContext).GetMethod("Translate"); I now get the exception System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException. So how do I target Translate<TEntity>?

Comment: There are two overloads called `Translate` - see [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.core.objects.objectcontext.aspx) - so you will have to pass the signature of the one you want to `GetMethod` using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hy0h0z1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of all of the above I came up with the following (which can still be improved):

```
public static class MultiResultsetsHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Given a data reader that contains multiple result sets, use the supplied object context to serialise the
        ///     rows of data in the result set into our property.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type of the containing object that contains all the various result sets.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="aDbReader">Database reader that contains all the result sets returned from the database.</param>
        /// <param name="aDbContext">Data context associated with the data reader.</param>
        /// <param name="aDataSetTypes">Type for each type to use when we call Translate() on the current result in the data reader.</param>
        /// <param name="aContainedDataSetReturnedTypes">
        ///     List of types in order of which the result sets are contained within the
        ///     data reader. We will serilize sequentially each result set the data reader contains
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>Retuns an object representing all the result sets returned by the data reader.</returns>
        public static T Process<T>(DbDataReader aDbReader, DbContext aDbContext, List<Type> aDataSetTypes, List<Type> aContainedDataSetReturnedTypes) where T : new()
        {
            //What we will be returning
            T result = new T();

            // Drop down to the wrapped `ObjectContext` to get access to the `Translate` method
            ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter) aDbContext).ObjectContext;

            //Iterate the passed in dataset types as they are in the same order as what the reader contains    
            for (int datasetNdx = 0; datasetNdx < aContainedDataSetReturnedTypes.Count; datasetNdx++)
            {
                //Advance the reader if we are not looking at the first dataset
                if (datasetNdx != 0)
                    aDbReader.NextResult();

                //Get the property we are going to be updating based on the type of the class we will be filling
                PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof (T).GetProperties().Single(p => p.PropertyType == aContainedDataSetReturnedTypes[datasetNdx]);

                //Now get the object context to deserialize what is in the resultset into our type
                MethodInfo method = GetTranslateOverload(typeof (ObjectContext));
                MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(aDataSetTypes[datasetNdx]);

                //Invoke the generic method which we hvae constructed for Translate
                object valueForProperty = generic.Invoke(objectContext, new object[] {aDbReader});

                //Finally we update the property with the type safe information
                propertyInfo.SetValue(result, valueForProperty);
            }
            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Internal helper method to get the necessary translate overload we need:
        ///     ObjectContext.Translate<T>(DbReader)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="aType">ObjectContext.GetType()</param>
        /// <returns>Returns the method we require, null on error.</returns>
        private static MethodInfo GetTranslateOverload(Type aType)
        {
            MethodInfo myMethod = aType
                .GetMethods()
                .Where(m => m.Name == "Translate")
                .Select(m => new
                             {
                                 Method = m,
                                 Params = m.GetParameters(),
                                 Args = m.GetGenericArguments()
                             })
                .Where(x => x.Params.Length == 1
                            && x.Args.Length == 1
                            && x.Params[0].ParameterType == typeof (DbDataReader)
                //            && x.Params[0].ParameterType == x.Args[0]
                )
                .Select(x => x.Method)
                .First();
            return myMethod;
        }
    }
```

So assuming you have:

```
public class UspGetSideBarListReturnDto
{
    public List<Set1ReturnDto> Dummy1 { get; set; }
    public List<Set2ReturnDto> Dummy2 { get; set; }
}

public class Set1ReturnDto
{
    public Int32 CruiseCount { get; set; }
    public string DisplayText { get; set; }
    public Int64 DisplayValue { get; set; }
}

public class Set2ReturnDto
{
    public string DepartingFrom { get; set; }
    public string Port_Code { get; set; }
}
```

You can call it as:

```
DbDataReader reader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();
return MultiResultsHelper.Process<UspGetSideBarListReturnDto>(reader, myDbContext, new List<Type>{typeof(Set1ReturnDto), typeof(Set2ReturnDto)}, new List<Type>{typeof(List<Set1ReturnDto>), typeof(List<Set2ReturnDto>});
```

The order of the aDataSetTypes needs to correspond to the list of result sets in the aDbReader.

Improvements would be:

- Only pass the list of dataset types. (And have the List properties automatically determined)