# How do I pass a list of types to a method call in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

- .NET 4.51

I am trying to declare a method where I can pass a list of classes via my parameter aListOfClasses viz:

```
public static class MyClass
{
  public static void MyCall(List<**WhatDoIPutHere**> aListOfClasses)
  {
    foreach (var item in aListOfClasses)
    {
      var typeInfo = typeof (item);
    }
  }
}
```

so if I have say a bunch of classes with no common base:

```
public class ClassOne
{

}

public class ClassTwo
{

}
```

I want to be able to call my method as followsL

```
var myListOfClasses = new List<????>();
myListOfClasses.Add(ClassOne);
myListOfClasses.Add(ClassTwo);

MyClass.MyCall(myListOfClasses);
```

So my questions are:

1. How do I declare aListOfClasses? What is the type?

Comment: List<object> could work for what you want.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @Enigmativity I am trying to achieve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31399498/generic-approach-to-dealing-with-multiple-result-sets-from-ef-stored-procedure using this knowledge gained from this question.

Comment: @deathismyfriend Ultimately that did not work for me as when I tried it with         public static void MyCall(List<object> aListOfClasses)
        {
            foreach (var listOfClass in aListOfClasses)
            {
                System.Type typeInfo = typeof(listOfClass);
            }
        }
I got a compiler error saying that listOfClass cannot be found. So for now I am going with Blorgbeard's solution below.

Answer (score 4):

You can declare your method like this:

```
public static void MyCall(List<Type> aListOfClasses)
{
    foreach (var item in aListOfClasses)
    {
        var typeInfo = item; // no need for typeof again
    }
}
```

And define your list like:

```
var myListOfClasses = new List<Type>();
myListOfClasses.Add(typeof(ClassOne));
myListOfClasses.Add(typeof(ClassTwo));
```

Comment: Thanks - that has helped me to get further in terms of what I am trying to achieve which is explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31399498/generic-approach-to-dealing-with-multiple-result-sets-from-ef-stored-procedure. Currently using your approach of List<Type> is giving me issues using the Translate<> method.